# LibreOffice does not detects my fonts

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I installed some truetype fonts in following folder:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/bfonts
```

Some softwares such as thunderbird detect my fonts and I can use them in those software's, but LibreOffice does not detect newly installed fonts. 
I tried restarting LibreOffice and restarting Ubuntu as well, but no success.
Any one could help me?

Comment: Ugh, five years later and I'm still having this problem. It doesn't find fonts in `~/.local/share/fonts`, `~/fonts`, `~/.fonts`, or any other user-specific path (yes all font files and the path itself are world-readable). I even closed LibreOffice entirely and ran `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to no avail. Why is LibreOffice so obtuse about fonts?

Answer (score 4):

The correct path for installing fonts *manually* is `/usr/local/share/fonts`. I did so and libreoffice picked up my fonts just fine. However `~/.fonts`, `/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts` and `/usr/share/fonts`---the latter two being exclusive to fonts provided by .deb packages---are equivalent from fontconfig's perspective.

I suspect a permissions problem. Take care that the font files are world readable. If they're not and you copy them with `sudo` they end up unreadable by libreoffice. That does not happen when copied into ~/.fonts by the user who then launches LO.

Comment: I just noticed that /usr/share/fonts as a drop zone for font files is being propagated all over the web. But that is still just wrong. That is not the point here, though.

Answer (score 1):

## Proportional True Type fonts are turned off by default

Go to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Fonts* where you will see:

[image: Libreoffice Non-Proportional Fonts.png]

Remove the check mark beside ***Non-proportional fonts only*** then click <kbd>OK</kbd> button. Now many more fonts will available for you including the ones you just installed that were missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Libre Office from snap package need link the fonts folder: [Any way to get fonts to work in Libreoffice snap package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881667/any-way-to-get-fonts-to-work-in-libreoffice-snap-package)

```bsh
cd ~/snap/libreoffice/current;
ln -s ~/.fonts .
```

Answer (score -1):

LibreOffice doesn't detect (I don't know why) fonts in /usr/share/fonts/, you have to put them in ~/.fonts and clear the cache with `sudo fc-cache -f -v`