# Any way to get fonts to work in Libreoffice snap package?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, snap

I have installed Libreoffice 5.3 via snap, but it is only able to use a limited number of fonts.  I have copied fonts into ~/.fonts and they still don't work.  Once I copied fonts into ~/.fonts other snaps (like inkscape) could use the, but still not LO.  Does anyone else have fonts working with LO or is this just a bug/limitation with the LO snap?  I welcome any advice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a limitation with the snap format.

Comment: I don't think it's a limitation of snaps.  It seems to just be a limitation of the Libreoffice snap.  Posts like [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/879468/inkscape-0-92-0-snap-fonts-problem-ubuntu-16-10?rq=1) indicate that other snap apps (like inkscape) can use fonts found in ~/.fonts.  Apparently, Libreoffice can't do that.  Is this a problem with the way that the snap is being packaged?  Some other problem?

Comment: Then I stand corrected, @AdamYork. Didn't know that `~/.fonts` works (sometimes) as opposed to `/usr/share/fonts`.

Answer (score 5):

You must copy your fonts in `~/.font` folder , then in terminal type `sudo fc-cache -fv` . go to this path `~/snap/libreoffice/current/` and make a link to `~/.fonts` folder by below command:

```
ln -s {source-filename} {symbolic-filename}
ln -s ~/.fonts .fonts
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "snap" version of Ubuntu, you will *not* be able to "see" any fonts you have installed in Ubuntu.

Close LibreOffice, if it is open.

Open Terminal - hold "Ctrl", "Alt" and press "T" - then enter:

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Change your "working" directory - that is, where you *are* in Terminal - to that of LibreOffice:

```
cd ~/snap/libreoffice/current
```

Create a symbolic link ("shortcut") to your font folder:

```
ln -s /home/your-ubuntu-username/.local/share/fonts
```

Then run this command:

```
ln -s ~/.fonts .fonts
```

This *should* work (it did for me just then!) and I've tried to make it as easy to follow as possible - but you don't feel comfortable using Terminal commands, you can always switch to the "regular" version of LibreOffice...

Open Ubuntu Software and search for "libreoffice" - remove the one that has references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" when you click on it (i.e. on the page that has the picture, description, etc...) - it *should* have these references under the "Details" section towards the bottom.

Hit the "back" arrow and install the "regular" version of the LibreOffice programs you need to use - these should *not* contain *any* references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" under the "Details" section at the bottom.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of answer above. Also it's unclear why two `ln` commands are necessary (don't they create two links in `~/snap/libreoffice/current`, `fonts -> ~/.local/share/fonts` and `.fonts -> ~/.fonts`? Why?)